# Claim an Amazon Connect phone number with AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-connect

I am trying to deploy a CloudFormation stack with this template.

```
---

Resources:
  # This has already been deployed successfully.
  ConnectInstance:
    Type: AWS::Connect::Instance
    Properties:
      Attributes:
        InboundCalls: True
        OutboundCalls: True
      IdentityManagementType: CONNECT_MANAGED
      InstanceAlias: !Ref AWS::StackName

  # This keeps failing to deploy.
  PhoneNumber:
    Type: AWS::Connect::PhoneNumber
    Properties: 
      CountryCode: US
      TargetArn: !GetAtt ConnectInstance.Arn
      Type: TOLL_FREE

Outputs:
  PhoneNumber:
    Value: !GetAtt PhoneNumber.Address
```

However, the `AWS::Connect::PhoneNumber` instance keeps failing to deploy with the following message.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Resource of type 'AWS::Connect::PhoneNumber' with identifier 'ARN_REDACTED' did not stabilize." (RequestToken: 77acda15-2de4-3152-ff11-0e972d1840d1, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)
```

Can anyone help with this?

I tried deploying multiple times but still got the same result every time. I also tried claiming a phone number manually on another instance that I created by hand, but I got an error saying I had reached the quota, even though I've never successfully claimed any numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue that will require a support ticket with Amazon.

The stand alone error message didn't explain how you may have gotten to where you are, so below I documented steps I took to recreate the issue.

**Primer:**

I started with a new clean AWS account and using the root user to deploy. I did this to ensure there wasn't already a conflict in the account or a previous instance created and because the root user has full privs (please note I understand working with the root user isn't best practice and do not advise this in a production setting).

**Steps to Recreate:**

1. Created Instance using CFN (MyFirstInstance) - (success)
2. Claimed Phone number using CFN (success)
3. Tried to Claim new Phone Number in Console (Limit Reached Error) (see quota reached error info below)
4. Checked Service Quota - Amazon Connect
5. Checked Service Quota - List Phone Numbers (Only one phone number claimed)
6. Deleted - Claimed Phone number CFN stack
7. Checked Service Quota - List Phone Numbers (List is now empty)
8. Deleted - Instance CFN Stack
9. ReCreated Instance using CFN (MyFirstInstance) - (success)
10. ReClaimed a Phone number using CFN (failed with did not stabilize error)
11. Tried to Claim new Phone Number in Console (Limit Reached Error)
12. ReCreated Instance using CFN (new logical id MySecondInstance) (success)
13. ReClaimed a Phone number using CFN (new logical id - MySecondPhoneNumber) - (failed with did not stabilize error)

**Take Away:** The initial deployment will work as intended. The instance was created and the phone number claimed. However, once an instance is created in the account and a phone number is claimed, that's when this stabilize error during the claiming of a phone number seems to surface. I'm sure this isn't the intended behavior but, it's what is being experienced and will require support. Using new logical id's and/or resource names do not help.

Additionally, (according to Amazon Connect's Administrator Guide in the "Amazon Connect service quotas" section) the Phone Number limit reached message may appear in the console even if it's the first time claiming a number and will require  support intervention as well. See below expert from amazon.

> I tried deploying multiple times but still got the same result every
> time. I also tried claiming a phone number manually on another
> instance that I created by hand, but I got an error saying I had
> reached the quota, even though I've never successfully claimed any
> numbers.

**Excerpt explaining (Phone numbers per instance):**

> It's possible to get an error message that "You've reached the limit
> of Phone Numbers," even if it's the first time you've claimed a phone
> number. All the issues that cause this error message require help from
> AWS Support to resolve.

Excerpt Source [here is the url of to find the answer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/amazon-connect-service-limits.html#connect-quotas):

Lastly, you can find at [my github related cloudformation files and supplemental screenshots](https://github.com/hacmia/so-amz-connect-claim-phone-number-cfn)